# What's the cheapest stable route to cross the Pacific?

Tags: air-travel, budget, sea-travel, oceania

One of the most difficult parts planning a round-the-world trip is figuring out how to cross the Pacific Ocean. If you have a big budget that's not a problem, but if you're trying to save each penny it could be the most expensive part of your trip.

To answer my question, let's assume we are in Australia or nearby countries and want to get to any country in American continent (North or South America). We can fly or take any sea transport. What's the cheapest way to do it?

NOTE: I've put the "stable" adjective to ensure that the answer will refer to a stabilised route with a non-volatile price, it is, it's not an special offer, a route-code trick or something similar. In other words, it means that anybody can find this price or similar any time.

Given all this, my best price is to fly from Sydney to Honolulu (Hawaii) and then to Las Vegas:

```
SYD-HNL from ~$400 
HNL-LAS from ~$200
```

Comment: Voted to close as 'too broad'. There are many different 'cheapest' fare at any given time of the year and therefore too many possible answers.

Comment: That's why I specified "stable" route: no big changes on different year dates

Comment: Don't you want to stop at one or more islands along the way?

Comment: If it's cheaper I have no problem to stop, but it's not necessary. To clarify, I'm looking for a reliable and cheap way to cross from Oceania or south of SEA to anywhere in the american continent (north or south). No problem if this imply a lot of stopovers or I have to take a ship + some flight.

Comment: I don't think you're going to find a ship for this route, unless you go back to SEA. And that would be much more expensive anyway.

Comment: Well, I'm not looking for a ship only, a flight is ok. The question is: which is the cheapest way to cross the Pacific flying or by sea?

Comment: The "stable" requirement would basically rule out travel by air entirely: air fares are highly volatile.  Why is this a requirement?  Can't you just book a flight, and then not care how the prices change from then on?

Comment: By the way: I suppose SEA means "southeast Asia"?  It's also the airport code for Seattle, so this confused me.

Comment: There is no stable route: the price rose at least 50% in Easter, Summer and Christmas

Comment: AND i check the price, it cost at least $700 for direct SYD-HNL and $550 for direct HNL-LAS

Comment: Las Vegas seems the best option, as a destination. There are also cheap flight from Bangkok (Thailand), which is better if you truly want to save pennies & avoid super expensive Australia.

Comment: @NateEldredge the stability is a requirement because the date is unknow due I'm asking to have an idea about how to cross the Pacific Ocean the day I arrive to Australia and have to cross it in my around-the-world trip. Anyway the "stable" price, has its limits, of course, I cannot pretend to buy a ticket for tomorrow in high season and pay the same than for a ticket 3 month in advance and low season. The "stable" should be understand as a goal, not as a strict rule.

Comment: @AdrienBe I've do some research and the cheapest prices I find for Bangkok are around $350 (BKK-LAX) and fly to BKK from Australia is not very expensive. The curious part of this is that this is that these BKK-LAX are not crossing the Pacific, they go to Europe and from there to LAX :-O But that's a good answer if you want to write it ;)

Comment: I am voting to close as this is price shopping

Answer (score 6):

I've done NZ/Aus to North America a few times, and spent ages and ages trying sneaky routes and tricks to get cheaper deals. Time usually doesn't bother me, so I really go for cheapest.

Firstly, remember that seasonal trends, changes, random spikes, holidays and promotions change the prices all the time. So asking for the 'cheapest' is not going to get an accurate answer, as it's in flux.

Saying that, generally I've found you have a few options:

- [findacrew.net](http://findacrew.net/) - if you're really lucky, you might find a boat going when and where you want it, for the cost of perhaps food and water, plus some work on the boat. I have a couple of friends who have done this across large bodies of water.  It's not for me though.
- cruise ships - too expensive by far.
- cargo boats.  This has been [considered often on here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/freighter-travel), but it's frequently impractical for time and often is more expensive than one might imagine.
- flying. This is pretty much it.  So at this point I've played with routes through SE Asia, Japan, many, many Pacific islands and occasionally through Europe.  What it comes down to usually is a few small routes that interchange for the cheapest:

  - through Bangkok. AirAsia, more recently cheap flights on Malaysian, and Jetstar specials have made this a much more feasible route. You just need that great flight between there and North America.
  - through Honolulu.  AKL/SYD/BNE to HNL (Jetstar has great deals on their new 787 for example), then an onward flight to LA/SLC/SEA with Air Alaska, Hawaiian or other.
  - through Fiji. What used to be a great route with Air Pacific, was rebranded as Fiji Airways, and I've not managed to find better prices since. They'd fly AKL->NAN(Nadi, Fiji)->HNL, and then onwards with Alaskan or others.
  - weirdly, through Dubai. I've seen this once or twice - amazing deals with Emirates and partners from Sydney, via Dubai, to North America. Go figure.  I've yet to use it though, but dream of the air miles...

Comment: Through Dubai would probably not count as "round the world" in most people's naive opinion. It could be part of an itinerary by the "route crosses its own antipode" definition if you continue to South America after that trip, though.